# JS: Sorting array by multiple fields doesn't works

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to create method that sort elements in this order:

1. 1st on the list has to be elements that are "active" (isActive field set to true). If both compared elements are active then sorted by alphabetical order.
2. Next elements on the list are these elements that have to fields (createSheet and centralBox) set to true. If both compared elements have this fields set to true then sorted by alphabetical order.
3. Next elements on the list are elements that have only centralBox field set to true. As every other case when both elements have these fields set to true, then sort by alphabetical order.
4. Next elements on the list are elements that have only createSheet field set to true. And the same as above...
5. Last sorting in hierarchy is sorting alphabetical

This is what I've made and it doesn't work (name is string, other fileds are booleans):

```
    sortingSelectList = (firstElement, secondElement) => {
    const elementToCompare = {
        name: firstElement.label.toLowerCase(),
        isActive: this.state.activeSystems.ids.includes(firstElement.label),
        createSheet: this.state.systems.entities[firstElement.label].createSheet,
        centralBox: this.state.systems.entities[firstElement.label].centralBox
    };
    const comparingElement = {
        name: secondElement.label.toLowerCase(),
        isActive: this.state.activeSystems.ids.includes(secondElement.label),
        createSheet: this.state.systems.entities[secondElement.label].createSheet,
        centralBox: this.state.systems.entities[secondElement.label].centralBox
    };

    if (elementToCompare.isActive < comparingElement.isActive) { return -1; }
    if (elementToCompare.isActive > comparingElement.isActive) { return 1; }

    if (elementToCompare.centralBox && elementToCompare.createSheet < comparingElement.centralBox && comparingElement.createSheet) { return -1; }
    if (elementToCompare.centralBox && elementToCompare.createSheet > comparingElement.centralBox && comparingElement.createSheet) { return 1; }

    if (elementToCompare.centralBox < comparingElement.centralBox) { return -1; }
    if (elementToCompare.centralBox > comparingElement.centralBox) { return 1; }

    if (elementToCompare.createSheet < comparingElement.createSheet) { return -1; }
    if (elementToCompare.createSheet > comparingElement.createSheet) { return 1; }

    if (elementToCompare.name < comparingElement.name) { return -1; }
    if (elementToCompare.name > comparingElement.name) { return 1; }

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me?

EXAMPLE:

```
Object 1: { name: B,
        isActive: true,
        createSheet: false,
        centralBox: false }
Object 2: { name: A,
        isActive: true,
        createSheet: false,
        centralBox: false }         
Object 3: { name: B,
        isActive: false,
        createSheet: false,
        centralBox: false }
Object 4: { name: B,
        isActive: false,
        createSheet: false,
        centralBox: true }
Object 5: { name: B,
        isActive: false,
        createSheet: true,
        centralBox: false }
Object 6: { name: B,
        isActive: false,
        createSheet: true,
        centralBox: true }
```

Expected order: Object2 -> Object1 -> Object6 -> Object4 -> Object5 -> Object3

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56972441/edit) then the snippet editor `[<>]` and provide a [mcve] with input and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be encoding and weighting objects based on your condition. Take a look at this code:

```js
var obj = [
{ name: "B",
  isActive: true,
  createSheet: false,
  centralBox: false },
{ name: "A",
  isActive: true,
  createSheet: false,
  centralBox: false },
{ name: "B",
  isActive: false,
  createSheet: false,
  centralBox: false },
{ name: "B",
  isActive: false,
  createSheet: false,
  centralBox: true },
{ name: "B",
  isActive: false,
  createSheet: true,
  centralBox: false },
{ name: "B",
  isActive: false,
  createSheet: true,
  centralBox: true }
]

for (const o of obj){
  let score = o.isActive === true ? 0 : 50
  score += o.centralBox === true ? 0 : 20
  score += o.createSheet === true ? 0 : 10
  score += o.name.charCodeAt(0)
  o.score = score
}
obj.sort((a, b) => a.score - b.score)
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Your welcome. If you feel so, upvote and mark it as best answer to help others who has the same problem as yours ;)

Comment: I will if I achive 15 reputations :)

Answer (score 0):

Comparisons have higher precedence than `&&`, so try changing

`(elementToCompare.centralBox && elementToCompare.createSheet < comparingElement.centralBox && comparingElement.createSheet)`
with

`((elementToCompare.centralBox && elementToCompare.createSheet) < (comparingElement.centralBox && comparingElement.createSheet))`

i.e. wrap what you want to compare in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate object to hold the sorting order you require. I've used the following code in the past, not my own but cant remember where i got it so cant give credit.

A positive direction denotes sorting in ascending order and a negative does the opposite

```
let sortBy = [{
  prop:'isActive',
  direction: 1
},{
  prop:'createSheet',
  direction: 1
},
{
  prop:'centralBox',
  direction: 1
},
{
  prop:'name',
  direction:1
}];
```

You then need to loop through each of the properties above, applying each to the array:

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
  let i = 0, result = 0;
  while(i < sortBy.length && result === 0) {
    result = sortBy[i].direction*(a[ sortBy[i].prop ].toString() < b[ sortBy[i].prop ].toString() ? -1 : (a[ sortBy[i].prop ].toString() > b[ sortBy[i].prop ].toString() ? 1 : 0));
    i++;
  }
  return result;
})
```

The `ToString` conversion makes the code more flexible so it can be applied in a large variety of sorting situations.

We also multiply by the direction you require.

Applying this to your array gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works but I used solution from agtabesh becouse it was easier to understand for noob like me :)

Answer (score -1):

You have a lot of different conditions. 
Sou for every condition store filtered results. Check [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.
At the end merge all arrays in one array. Check [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) function.